# C# WinForms How to add Chart to Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, panel, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to add dynamically charts to a panel in C# WinForms but haven't had any success yet.

Situation:
I have a form (Form1) with a button (button1) and a panel. After the button (button1) is clicked a dialog shows up.

When Dialog.Result from the dialog (Form2) is OK, it should add a chart into the panel with some random value. Multiple charts should be able to be added to the panel.

What I tried so far:
I made a separate class (addGraph) where I wrote a function which creates a column chart with 2 values. Than I tried to call the function in the dialog (Form2) class but this didn't worked out like expected and showed nothing in the (Form1) panel.

Question:
How can I achieve to add charts to the Form1 with function calling in Form2?
Also should I use Panel or GraphControl?

Thanks  for your help.
Greetings

Comment: a) you ought to have shown your code b) what is _GraphControl_? c) the (correct) answers tell you to make some control (panel, tabpage, form etc) the `Parent` of the new chart. This is correct. It is the same as adding it to the container control's `Controls` collection. Also note that each chart needs to have its location set so that they don't all sit at 0,0 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like this :

```
void Button1_click()
{
   using (Form2 form2 = new Form2())
   {
      if (form2.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         var chart = create your chart here
         chart.Parent = YourPanel;
      }
   }
}
```

if the chart is created on Form2 than it will look more like

```
void Button1_click()
{
   using (Form2 form2 = new Form2())
   {
      if (form2.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         var chart = form2.CreateChart();
         chart.Parent = YourPanel;
      }
   }
}
```

and on Form2 you will need a public function called `CreateChart()` that will create the chart off course

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to send link from Form1 to Form2 when creating Form2.

in Form1:

```
void Button_click()
{
   Form2 form = new Form2();
   form.parent = this;
   form.Show();
}
```

in Form2:

```
private Form parent;
void Add_Chart()
{
   var chart= CreateSomeRandomeChart();
   this.parent.createChart(chart);
}
```

Comment: your Form2 is not showed as Dialog like the OP requested in his question so your chart will always be created not only when the user clicks on OK on Form2